# python import breaks in server environment but works fine on my computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-unittest, python-2.4

I have a research server I am using to run some python scripts.  The server only has python 2.4.  My problem is that when I try to run the tests on the server, it breaks on import statements.  My file structure is this:

```
|-- README.md
|-- poly.py
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_foil.py
```

`tests/__init__.py` looks like

```
from test_foil import *
unittest.main()
```

and `test_foil.py` initially looks like

```
import unittest
from poly import Poly
```

On my computer, when I run `python tests/__init__.py` the tests execute.  But when I run it on the server I get the error

```
from test_foil import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
    from test_foil import *
  File "/home/simon_team/partition_poly/tests/test_foil.py", line 2, in ?
    from poly import Poly
ImportError: No module named poly
```

It is not 100% critical to run the tests on the server, but it would be a really convenient way of making sure the code is 2.4 compatible before running actual code.  I can't for the life of me figure out why it is behaving differently on the two machines, since the docs don't indicate that the behavoir of `import` changed from 2.4 to 2.7

Comment: Where is the poly module?

Comment: Yeah, unittest is on the server.  I guess I should just see about getting 2.7 or 3.4 installed.

Comment: irh, sorry I edited that, unittest is not the problem, the problem is that the system cannot find poly. Can you try finding a version for it and doing a pip install just to see if it is there?

Comment: Or copy paste the poly.py source code.

Comment: `poly` is my code, defined in `poly.py`

Comment: OK, please check the build path for poly.py and make sure that it is in the same directory as test_foil.py on the server

Comment: hmm, how exactly do I do that?  Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: What folder is poly.py located in on the server? Where are you hosting?

Comment: The folder structure is given in the question at the top... poly.py is located in the project folder.  Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Never mind, I just saw your file structure :P. No kudos for paying attention.  Try using /home/simon_team/partition_poly as the build path (I got the build from the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.path.append("path_to_directory")

from poly import Poly
```

Comment: I added a * after import just now

Comment: Getting invalid syntax errors:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tests/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
        from test_foil import *
      File "/home/simon_team/partition_poly/tests/test_foil.py", line 2
        from /home/simon_team/partition_poly/poly import Poly
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: replacing the slashes with dots should help

Comment: Or what helps is simply putting the entire build path in one import

Comment: Dots doesn't work "ImportError: No module named home.simon_team.partition_poly.poly" (I added an __init__.py to the project folder for good measure and nothing changed).  WHen you say to put the build path in an import do you mean modifying the sys.path?

Comment: I just realized, that method works with Python 2.5 and higher. I am working on a solution now. I'll get back to you in a bit

Comment: :/  Annoying indeed.  Thanks so much for all the help though.

Comment: No problem, currently, you can add the parent directory to the PYTHONPATH (I'm trying to figure out a way to do that) and then just do import parentdirectory.file

Comment: I get the error that "no module named parent".  However the following works: 
from poly import Poly.  Ill edit your solution with what works.

Comment: I meant put the name of the parent folder which is partition_poly

Comment: Ah.., of course.  Feel silly.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help any other time